# Auto rotate camera change direction when limit

Tags: three.js

How to make camera auto rotate right and up, if it reach the limit so it rotate right and down like this demo (http://carvisualizer.plus360degrees.com/threejs/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get a smooth up-and-down with easing, you can use a sine wave. The core part of the animation looks like this:

```
angle += speed;
camera.position.y = centerY + (Math.sin(angle) * waveHeight);
```

I made a [a JSFiddle you can check out](http://jsfiddle.net/matthewcooley/mhq7F/). You can play with the centerY, speed, and waveHeight properties to get the feel you want.

The example also has a quick-and-dirty way to spin around an object.

Comment: Seem like it got problem when i add Orbitcontrol, here [JsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mhq7F/2/)

Comment: Your script and Orbitcontrols are fighting. You'll have to build in some logic to let one or the other control the camera. After quick glance at Orbitcontrols it looks like you can watch the `state` property (you'll need to make it public), and if its -1 run your logic, otherwise run its logic. You’ll want to tween the camera in your custom controls so it won’t suddenly jump when your own script takes back over. I built out the skeleton here: http://jsfiddle.net/matthewcooley/Q72wU But you’ll need to add the actual `state` lookup.

Comment: @user972611 forgot to tag you in the above comment.

Answer (score 1):

you can just add some conditions in render function..

```
if(camera.rotation.x <= 100)
    camera.rotation.x +=0.01;
else if(camera.rotation.x > 100)
    camera.rotation.x -= 0.01;
```

have a try in your code..

Comment: @user972611 let me know what problem you faced? share your code might help.